# how to replace a keyword with a link using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, str-replace, simple-html-dom

how to find `hello` keyword in a html content inside `<p>` tag directly (not sub tags e.g. `<a>` tag) and replace it with a link

**i dont want alter the html attributes**

**HTML:**

```
<p>hello world
    <a href="hello.html">hello</a>
</p>
<img src="hello.png" alt="image" />
```

**I need an output like this:**

```
<p><a href="hello">hello</a> world
    <a href="hello.html">hello</a>
</p>
<img src="hello.png" alt="image" />
```

**not this:**

```
<p><a href="hello">hello</a> world
    <a href="<a href="hello">hello</a>.html">hello</a>
</p>
<img src="<a href="hello">hello</a>.png" alt="image" />
```

**What i tried**

```
include('inc/simple_html_dom.php');
// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();

// Load HTML from a string

$dom = '
<p>hello world
    <a href="hello.html">hello</a>
</p>
<img src="hello.png" alt="image" />
';

$html->load($dom);

foreach($html->find('p') as $p)
{
    $p->innertext = str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $p->innertext);
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: Why don't you do this in JavaScript?

Comment: @GuyT google and other search engines can see those links?

Comment: That's a point I didn't think of. I guess Google will not see this because a Google bot will read the page as plain text. I'm working on a PHP solution ;)

Comment: does this fit your needs? http://viper-7.com/UaSYBt

Comment: @GuyT no i tried that before :), i have an idea, replace all hello with link then find all attributes from tags and remove <a> tag from the attributes

Comment: What are your exact requirements? Is it possible that 'hello' will be multiple times in the first sentence(or not at all)?

Comment: @GuyT yes it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
foreach($html->find('text') as $text){
  if($text->parent->tag != 'p') continue;
  $text->outertext = str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $text->outertext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this particular case, if you set

```
$searchArray = 'hello ';  // with a blank space after hello
```

it should work as you wish